# c++ double to byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, byte

I want to cast `double` numbers to byte array (unsigned char*)

```
std::vector<unsigned char*> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        double a = 3.14+i;
        double b = 4.44+i;

        v.push_back((unsigned char*)&a);
        v.push_back((unsigned char*)&b);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        std::cout << *((double*)v.at(i)) << std::endl;
```

i've done this, but it always gives me last set of numbers.

current output:

```
7.14
8.44
7.14
8.44
7.14
8.44
7.14
8.44
7.14
8.44
```

How it is supposed to be:

```
3.14
4.44
4.14
5.44
5.14
6.44
6.14
7.44
7.14
8.44
```

Comment: vector<T*> is a vector of pointers, not a vector of Ts.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this in the first place? Why not just store a vector of doubles?

Comment: Not an answer, but just things to do to remedy your case without changing too much: **1** Declare your *a* and *b* as `double *` instead. **2** Initialize them with `new double(whatever + i)` instead. **3** Get rid of the ampersand `&` behind them in the following couple of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<unsigned char*>` is a vector (list) of pointers to `unsigned char`. This is not what you want.

I guess you want to have `std::vector<unsigned char>` (no pointers here).

For each number you want to add to the list, you have to add several (typically 8) bytes to it. In order to do it, the simplest method is:

```
const unsigned char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&a);
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(double); ++i)
    v.push_back(ptr[i]);
```

To extract a number from such an array of bytes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    double number;
    memcpy(&number, &v.at(i * sizeof(double)), sizeof(double));
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really wrong you are saving **pointers** to address that would be out of scope (`a` and `b`), this would cause invalid memory access (would work as you expected OR would not).

You are declaring a vector of pointer (`std::vector<unsigned char*>`) not a vector of unsigned char (`std::vector<unsigned char>`).

According to the output of this sample, it appear as if GCC (version 4.9.0) it reusing the same memory for variables `a and b` in the loop OR extracted away the variables of the loop. Because it prints only two different address of the pointer storage in the vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned char*> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        double a = 3.14 + i;
        double b = 4.44 + i;

        v.push_back((unsigned char*)&a);
        v.push_back((unsigned char*)&b);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << ((double*)v.at(i)) << std::dec << std::endl;
        std::cout << *((double*)v.at(i)) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0x22fec0  -> Address 1
7.14
0x22fec8  -> Address 2
8.44
0x22fec0  -> Address 1
7.14
0x22fec8  -> Address 2
8.44
0x22fec0  -> Address 1
7.14
0x22fec8  -> Address 2
8.44
0x22fec0  -> Address 1
7.14
0x22fec8  -> Address 2
8.44
0x22fec0  -> Address 1
7.14
0x22fec8  -> Address 2
8.44
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the address of temporary variables `a` and `b` to the vector. In your example (by chance), on each loop `a` and `b` get assigned at the same location (in general, the behavior is not well-defined, they might get assigned in different locations, or they might even get reallocated later on, so the pointers might point to some other variables), so when you print the the content of where `v[i]` points to, you always get the content of `a` and `b` at the last iteration.

Edit:
Look at NetVipeC's answer, he is explaining it much better :-)

Comment: I don't know about the C++ standards, but if they are similar to C's in this matter, the assignments happen at the same location only by chance and not due to some language specification.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin you are absolutely right, it is by chance. I meant that, will edit the answer to reflect that. Thanks for noting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want what you expect, use new operator to create the doubles,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::vector<unsigned char*> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        double *a = new double (3.14+i);
        double *b = new double (4.44+i);

        v.push_back((unsigned char*) a);
        v.push_back((unsigned char*) b);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        std::cout << *((double*)v.at(i)) << std::endl;

    // remember to free the spaces you've allocated
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        delete v.at(i);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Convert the double to a string first then read each character from the string into the char array.